# QLabel higlight searched word

Tags: c++, qt, highlight, qlabel

I'm developing a Qt application and I'm trying to implement this feature where if you type a word all it's occurences in a QLabel get highlighted. I'm not sure how to do it. Is there a way for iterate through text in QLabel and change the background colour of certain word?

It can be done using in QTextEdit by using `QTextEdit::ExtraSelection`. But QLabel doesn't have this method.

So for example if the searched word is "sed" I want to get something like this in my QLabel:

[image]

Comment: You could show an example of what you want to get.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc I added an example. I hope it clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @madasionka we mean an example of code, not a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Qt rich text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) to add some style to the subtext. You will need to search for it yourself in the text string and insert some HTML.

```
This is my <span style="background-color:yellow">text</span>
```

An example to highlight a word into existing label (already containing the text) :

```
QString searchedWord = "sed";

QString txt = lbl->text();
txt.replace(QRegExp("\\b" + searchedWord + "\\b"),
            "<span style=\"background-color:yellow\">" + searchedWord + "</span>");
lbl->setText(txt);
```

If you want to highlight more than one word, you will need to make a more specific RegExp.